# Does $R=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} : 3|(x+y)\}$ define an equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, relations, equivalence-relations

Given $R=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} : 3|(x+y)\}$, Is $R$ reflexive? Is $R$ symmetric? Is $R$ transitive?

- **Reflexivity**: Could $(1,1)$ be a counter-example because $3\nmid(1+1)$?
- **Symmetry**: addition is commutative, so if $3∣(x+y)$, then $3∣(y+x)$ because $x+y=y+x$.
- **Transitivity**: I can't come up with a counter-example so I assume it must be true, but how do I prove that it is true? Given that $3∣(x+y)$ and $3∣(y+z)$, does $3∣(x+z)$?

Answer (score 4):

- For the reflexivity $(1,1)$ is a good counter example
- For the symmetry your reasoning is fine and correct
- For the transitivity it's false $x=z=1$ $y=2$

Answer (score 1):

Your example works fine to show that the relation is not reflexive.

As to transitivity, a proof approach might notice that if 3 divides both $x+y$ and $y+z$, then it divides $(x+y)-(y+z) = x-z$.  However, we want $3$ to divide $x+z$ instead, so it is likely that it might be a good idea to look harder for counterexamples.

Comment: Okay, so just off of the top of my head, 3∣(1+2) and 3∣(2+1), therefore x=1, y=2, and z=1, but 3∤2? This should be fine, since even though x=z this doesn't matter since they are both integers.

Comment: Yeah, you are totally allowed to use the same values for $x$ and $z$ in checking for transitivity. (This counterexample is also presented in Elaqqad's answer).